Getting "Public key is neither compressed or uncompressed" after trying to send with imported key
I still have a private key from an old Bitcoin wallet (circa 2012), and I have a private key. I downloaded the bitWallet app for iOS, entered my private key there and my wallet with balance and all transactions was displayed. I wanted to transfer bitcoins to my new wallet, but I get the following error:

mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Public key is neither compressed or uncompressed)

My secret key is 52 characters long, starts with 5HpH….
Step 1: in the bitWallet (iOS) application I insert the private key, and it automatically calculates the correct address.
Step 2: I click “save” and see my wallet with balance and list of transactions

Step 3: I'm trying to transfer bitcoins to my main wallet, I enter the address, click "Done" and get an error:



If you added the private key to a bitWallet wallet, the money is already in your wallet so I don't understand why you want to transfer the money from one of your bitWallet wallets to a different bitWallet wallet.

The error message is typical of people manually constructing transactions bit it seems unlikely that this is what you are doing. Can you describe exactly what you did step by step?

@RedGrittyBrick all because I can’t make transfers, because when I try to send funds I see an error: error mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Public key is neither compressed or uncompressed)
so I thought the best thing would be to withdraw funds to a new main wallet

@RedGrittyBrick How can I contact you for a quicker discussion? I promise, if you succeed, you won't regret it. your efforts will be rewarded

Sorry, I'm not interested in any reward. Please consider carefully what you ask for, you will mainly attract scammers.

@RedGrittyBrick I understand what you mean. but what should I do with my wallet? there's quite a good amount there

Since "make transfer", "send funds" and "withdraw funds" are all using the same underlying mechanism in a normal self-custodial wallet, I would either ask the wallet developer for support or import the private key into a more reliable wallet application.

@RedGrittyBrick I tried various options, all to no avail. but my knowledge in this area is negligible, and perhaps I am not noticing an obvious thing. I'm sure if you saw everything in more detail you would understand what's going on. can i leave you my gmail or twitter? I hope very much for your help! I saw from your answers that you understand this

I participate in this website because I enjoy it and because every answer might possibly help multiple people. A private gmail/twitter conversation holds no attraction for me. Sorry.

@RedGrittyBrick OK. then tell me what information should I provide so that you can help me here? I am sure that this information will be useful to many people, I searched on Google, there are many similar questions but I did not find a solution

If I had this problem I would repeat the whole import and transfer process and take screenshots of every single step. I would edit the screenshots to obscure any sensitive data and then edit the question to include the screenshots. If no one else could answer the question because they don't use Sollico Software's "BitWallet" app or don't use IOS, I would try to import the private key into Bitcoin core. Bear in mind that I don't use IOS and may not be able to help. But there are many others who may.

@RedGrittyBrick I added screenshots

@iKey did you tried with Blue Wallet? It's pretty good supporting old wallets.

You revealed an unsafe amount of your private key. Please move your money out of that address as quickly as possible! I have removed the image from the question. Please delete the image and move your funds as quickly as you can. Blue Wallet seems like a good option.

Will undelete after the image has been redacted.

@iKey: The image in question has been redacted. Note that it is still available on the image sharing platform. Please move your funds to safety as soon as possible.

The error message is unhelpful. I'd maybe import the private key into a different (but mainstream popular self-custodial) wallet app in the hope of at least getting a more useful error message.
